# Get radio button value on submit with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have this pretty basic HTML here that I'm going to be turning into an iframe eventually, it's basically just a simple widget that gets a score on the users end and then I want it to send the data back to my rails backend. Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to get the score when a user checks a button and hits submit.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Net Promoter Score!</h1>
  <form id="NPSform"; style= "text-align:center">

    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="1" value="1"> 1
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="2" value="2"> 2
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="3" value="3"> 3
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="4" value="4"> 4
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="5" value="5"> 5
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="6" value="6"> 6
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="7" value="7"> 7
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="8" value="8"> 8
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="9" value="9"> 9
    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="10" value="10"> 10
    <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>


<script>

var scores


</script>
</html>
```

How can I get the score when a user hits submit?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to submit the form and send the data using ajax ??
Or just simply want to do direct  form post??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Strictly Using Ruby on Rails**

Since all of your radio button elements use the same `name` attribute, only the selected value is going to be posted to the server.

So when you submit the form, you should be able to access the value using the corresponding `name` value of "scores" using the `params` collection :

```
params[:scores]
```

You can [read more about using parameters for Ruby on Rails here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).

**Using Javascript**

If you wanted to retrieve your selected value using Javascript when your `<form>` was submitted, you could create an event listener to listen for the `submit` event to be triggered and then grab the selected value :

```
<!-- Notice the getScore() function will be called when the form is submitted -->
<form id="NPSform" ... onsubmit='getScore();'>
  <!-- Elements omitted for brevity -->      
  <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
   function getScore(){
       // Get the selected score (assuming one was selected)
       var score = document.querySelector('input[name="scores"]:checked').value;
       alert(score + ' was selected!');
   }
</script>
```

You can [see an example of this demonstrated here](http://jsbin.com/jasate/edit?html,output) and seen below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want value using jquery, you can do something like

```
$('input[name=mysubmit]').on('click', function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log($('input[name=scores]:checked').val());
});
```